# Creating Function in MySQL in 1 Row

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I have created function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `push_admin`(`p_messenger` text, `p_admin_id` int(20), `p_client_id` int(20))
RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO messenger(admin_id, client_id, messenger)
        VALUES (p_admin_id, p_client_id, p_messenger);
    INSERT INTO messenger(ref_id)
        SELECT id FROM messenger WHERE client_id = p_client_id;
    RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();    
END$$
```

How can I give `admin_id`, `client_id`, `messenger`, `ref_id` in 1 row?

Comment: What do you mean by giving? Are you asking how to call a user defined function in mysql? The same way as you call any pre-defined function.

Answer (score 0):

In your phpmyadmin under routines where you have added this function you will find an option to add parameters. see the image below  -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This option will suit you?

```
INSERT INTO messenger(admin_id, client_id, messenger, ref_id)
VALUES (p_admin_id, p_client_id, p_messenger, (SELECT id FROM messenger WHERE client_id = p_client_id));
```

Comment: Is auto-incremented ID field?

Comment: Can you help me Dennis :)

Comment: id in messenger table is  auto-incremented

Comment: It is unlikely that you will do this one request. You can make a trigger for a table to insert and there after recording interjection here to get the value of the `id`. Then, change the value of the `ref_id`.

Comment: sorry but i just can use stored function :(

Comment: If at the time of inserting the record value of the `id` field is unknown, the same query solve your problem fail.

Comment: Oops! I did not understand what you mean. Replace `INSERT` in second query to `REPLACE` or using `UPDATE` query

Comment: oh tks. i dit it? tks so much :)

Comment: Can you online facebook and help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Referring image added]
in picture is 2 rows. I want admin_id, client_id, messenger, ref_id in 1 row. Tks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `INSERT` in second query to `REPLACE`

```
CREATE FUNCTION `push_admin`(`p_messenger` text, `p_admin_id` int(20), `p_client_id` int(20))
RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO messenger(admin_id, client_id, messenger)
        VALUES (p_admin_id, p_client_id, p_messenger);
    REPLACE INTO messenger(ref_id)
        SELECT id FROM messenger WHERE client_id = p_client_id;
    RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();    
END$$
```

This will help you?

REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

[See REPLASE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, he wanted this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `push_client`(`p_email` text, `p_messenger` text, `p_phone` text, `p_domain` text, `p_ip` text, `p_browser` text, `p_admin_id` int(20), `p_client_id` int(20))
RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
    SET @id = 0;

    SELECT id INTO @id FROM messenger WHERE client_id = p_client_id AND admin_id = p_admin_id;

    INSERT INTO client(ref_id, email, phone, ip, browser)
        VALUES(@id, p_email, p_phone, p_ip, p_browser);

    UPDATE client SET domain_id = (SELECT id FROM domain WHERE name = p_domain);

    INSERT INTO messenger(client_id)
        SELECT id FROM client WHERE id = p_client_id;

    UPDATE messenger 
    SET admin_id = p_admin_id, browser = p_browser, messenger = p_messenger
    WHERE client_id = p_client_id;

    RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();    
END$$
```